# Rails - How to display API response on Views?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api

I am building a rails app that connects to [Yelp API](https://github.com/Yelp/yelp-ruby). I created `scrape` method:

```
  def scrape
    @results = Yelp.client.search(params[:location], {limit: 5, category_filter: "dessert"})
    ...
    redirect_to :posts
  end
```

When I tried this on **Rails Console**, I can confirm that it worked.

```
results.businesses[0].name
#=> Super awesome dessert place! #it returns the right response on console
```

But when I used it on views, it is not showing anything.

```
<div class="form-group">
  <%= form_tag({:controller=>"posts", :action=>"scrape"}, method: :post) do %>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= text_field_tag :location, nil, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Location', style:"width: 50%", :required => true %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= submit_tag 'Search!', name: nil, class: 'btn btn-success search-button'%>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>

<div class="center-block">
  <% if @results.blank? %>
    <h3>No result found</h3>
  <% else %>
    <% @results.businesses.each do |result| %>
...
<%= result.name %>
```

I get `'No result found'`. I have a feeling it is the way I setup my form-group to interact with the controller, and that it is  not querying yelp when I pressed the search button.

How can I store the result of such API call and display the result on views?

This is more of a Rails question, you don't have to necessarily have tried Yelp. When `Yelp.client.search('Some City', ...)` is invoked, Yelp responds back by sending a list of restaurants in 'Some City'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your `scrape` action is redirecting to the posts index action, in which case the `@result` variable you are setting in the `scrape` action is being ignored. One way to correct this would be to change the redirect to `render :posts`, in which case your `@results` variable should be available to the posts index view.

Comment: Thanks! Somehow it didn't work when I do `render :posts` but `:index` worked. However, you led me into the right direction! 
If you don't mind - may I ask one follow-up question? Is it right to say that the problem with my code is `@results` was run, but `redirect` runs and completed the code through before `@results` ever reached view, and that's why it is not showing any value?

If not, do you mind explaining further (in addition to the comment above) why the code didn't work before?

Comment: That sounds right -- redirecting passed the flow to a whole new controller and as I understand this would blow away any instance variables you previously set. The only instance variables available to your view after the redirect are ones set in the new action you redirected to.